# LD_PRELOAD with boost fileystem library

Tags: c++, c, linux, boost

I am trying to intercept open system call in Linux. It works fine with other libraries but doesn't wotk with boost libboost_fileystem. Here is my code (stripped down for readability).

```
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

typedef int (*open_func_type)(const char * pathname, int flags, ...);

int open(const char *path, int flags, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  mode_t mode = 0;
  if (flags & O_CREAT)
    {
      va_start(arg, flags);
      mode = va_arg(arg, mode_t);
      va_end(arg);
    }

  //some stuff here
  open_func_type open_func = (open_func_type) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
  return open_func(path, flags, mode);
}

int main()
{
   boost::filesystem::fstream build_path;
   build_path.open("/tmp/test.txt", ios::in);

   //other stuff
   return 0;
}
```

I stepped though the code using gdb, my open implementation doesn't get called. But doing strace shows the open system call being called. If I call other library functions that call open, I see my implementation getting called. Anything that I am doing wrong here? I am dynamically linking with boost libraries.

Comment: You're not intercepting the `open` system call, you're intercepting the `open` library function.

Comment: You also aren't using `LD_PRELOAD`.  If you were, this would probably be working.

Comment: Well it's not exactly LD_PRELOAD and system call but I think this should have worked for similar reasons the LD_PRELOAD works.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not loaded ahead of the library it's trying to intercept and also because it doesn't intercept the system call. If it did either of those two things it would work. But since it doesn't do either of them, the library still calls the regular `open` function which calls the system call which isn't intercepted.

Comment: System calls are in the kernel so I think in order to intercept them we have to intercept the library calls that call them. Also my understanding is that the executable is loaded first and then it's dependencies are resolved. This thing works fine if you create your own dynamic library(instead of boost) that calls open. Boost internally seems to use std::filebuf, probably this library is calling a different function that in turns calls the open system call in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I gave sometime to figure it out and found that internally boost calls std::basic_filebuf open which in turn calls fopen. fopen seems to call open system call in the kernel without calling open library call (it would be nice if somebody could point it out why). I intercepted fopen call and this works fine now. If large file support is used, fopen64 also needs to be implemented.

Comment: For one thing, `fopen` may wind up calling `mmap` if the file is opened read-only. (See glibc's `libio/iofopen.c` file.)